# How to remove fixed digits in column in R that also has words?

Tags: r, string, vector, transform

I have a vector that has a series of numbers and words.

`df <- as.character(c(1234, "Other", 5678, "Abstain"))`

I would like to remove the last two digits of the numbers without affecting the words in the string.

`df <- as.character(c(12, "Other", 56, "Abstain"))`

Comment: Well, vectors in R can't contain a mix of numbers and character values. It already probably converted to all characters. The code you provided above isn't actually valid R code (unless `Other` and `Abstain` are variables defined elsewhere). It would be better if you you provided a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) just to make things more clear.

Comment: Lacking that, you might be able to use `gsub("[0-9]{2}$", "", df)`. Note that this will change `"56"` to `""`.

Comment: @r2evans was right. That code worked perfectly. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably a bit more robust/versatile/safe than the solution suggested by @r2evans in the comments.

```
gsub( "(\\d{2,})\\d{2}$", "\\1", df)
```

what it does:

**pattern** = `"(^\\d{2,})\\d{2}$"`

- `^` matches the start of the string
- `\\d{2,}` matches any substring of *at least* two digits (delete the comma of you only want to match strings of the exact length of 4 digits)
- `(^\\d{2,})` the round brackets define the start from the string and the following repetition of minimal two digits as a group.
- `\\d{2}` a repetition of exactly two digits
- `$` matches the end of a string

in short: it matches any string that exits solely of digits, that starts with a minimum of two digits, andd ends with two digits (so the minimum length of the digit string = 4)

**replacement** = `"\\1"`

- replaces the entire matches string woth the first defind group ( `(^\\d{2,})` ) from the above described pattern.

### sample data

```
df <- c(123, "Other", 5678, "Abstain", "b12345", 123456, "123aa345")

gsub("(^\\d{2,})\\d{2}$", "\\1", df)
#[1] "123"      "Other"    "56"       "Abstain"  "b12345"   "1234"     "123aa345"
```